# union of list in ocaml without using library

Tags: ocaml

I have a assignment which requires writing a code to union list without using any library functions
this is my code

```
let rec union (l1:'a list) (l2:'a list) =
  let rec f x l = match l with
    | [] -> true
    | hd::tl ->
      if x = hd then false else f x tl
   in
  match l2 with
  | [] -> l1
  | hd::tl ->
    if f hd l1 then
      union hd::l1 tl
    else
      union l1 tl
```

but the compiler said that "This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a list The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list"

can somebody helps me to find out where did I do wrong? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need some parentheses on the last line:

```
if f hd l1 then union (hd::l1) tl else union l1 tl
```

In OCaml function application (as in `f x`) has very high precedence. So without these parens the expression is interpreted as `(union hd) :: (l1 tl)`.

(This code is pretty nice. Maybe rename `f` to something more descriptive such as `notmem`.)

Comment: Thank u a lot! It turns out that I do forget the parentheses, I thought Ocaml can interpret it automatically, didnt know it is so sensitive.